# How to use prepend in a refine

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make work the following code :

```
require 'ostruct'

module InteractorsRefine

  module OpenStructPrepend
    def delete_field(name)
      super(name) if self.__send__(name)
    end
  end

  refine OpenStruct do
    prepend OpenStructPrepend
  end
end


module Testy
  include InteractorsRefine
  person = OpenStruct.new('name' => 'John Smith', 'age' => 70)
  person.delete_field('namedddd')
end
```

You can execute the code here : https://repl.it/qvk/2

The purpose is to overide the delete_field of OpenStruct using both prepend and refine.

But the execution return NameError: method `namedddd' not defined in Class.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `refinement`s, you should use [`using`](http://dev.af83.com/2012/11/05/ruby-2-0-module-refine.html) instead of `include`:

```
module Testy
  using InteractorsRefine
  person = OpenStruct.new('name' => 'John Smith', 'age' => 70)
  person.delete_field('namedddd')
end
```

Hope that helps!